# Cell view shrink animation is jerky

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to shrink a custom cell view. I want the view beneath it to go up smoothly as the cell shrinks. However with my current implementation, the cell shrinks and there is a gap under it and after the animation is complete the tableview reloads.

```
CGRect    cellFrame = self.frame;

cellFrame.size.height -= 50;

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                 animations:^{
    self.topSpaceDescriptionView.constant -= cellFrame.size.height;
    self.frame = cellFrame;

    [self.superview layoutIfNeeded];
    [self.superview setNeedsLayout];
}
completion:^(BOOL finished __unused) {
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
    [self.tableDelegate refreshTable];
}];
```

Comment: When you change your layout and animate it, you should also be calling `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` on the tableView?

Comment: I'm calling this in my custom cell class.

Comment: You can pass the reference of the tableView in cellForRowAt or get the superView.